# A simple java encrypt/decrypt app for MS word files

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, encryption, aes

I am banging my head to setup for this small project. I am not able to find out the exact tools and setup to do the following. I am a bit new to java. Please suggest me something

Create a simple java application where you will just select a file file in the app and then encrypt/decrypt the file(MS word).

I am planning to use AES algo for the above purpose. Currently my setup is as follows

1. OS - Windows 7
2. IDE - Eclipse Indigo
3. Java installed
4. For the GUI purpose I am planning to use java swing
5. For AES encryption I don't know which library is available in java

Can anybody help me in selecting some best tools for java swing GUI designer and AES encryption library which I can add to eclipse. I know how to add the plugin for eclipse. But I don't know how add an external library to eclipse.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html    0.0001 seconds of google time for "java aes".

Comment: You should do your own search before posting questions. StackOverflow is not Google: it is using real people's time.

Comment: *"Can anybody help me in selecting some best tools.."* 1) Brain. 2) Research. 3) Effort. -- Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For the encryption, you can use the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) library via the [JCE/JCA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) interfaces.